# Show component identifiers in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

When I create a button, I'd like to be able to assign an identifier to it (and see this identifier when the component is clicked on), so that I can manipulate it programatically.

How can I go about doing this in the Interface Builder? (not using the "ctrl-drag" method).

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag)?

Comment: @JefferyThomas I've tried ctrl-dragging and assigning a name to the button that way (like you'd do for an action or outlet). What does "tag" actually do? (Yes, I've looked at the documentation, but am looking for a simple explanation, without all the other technical info).

Comment: `tag` puts a number on an instance of a view. You can assign the tag in IB and check for it in the target action (`sender.tag`) or search for it in the view controller (`self.view.viewWithTag(tagValue)`).